# last modified date after edit function

Tags: javascript

I want to display a "Last modified time" in my javascript table. I have searched a lot on date time but I can only find the last modified time on the document. I have some variables in my table (see below question). What i want to do is display the date after i was modified that variable. Can anyone help me ? :)

The table what im using with javascript.
`

```
if(response.length > 0)
{
    for (var count = 0;count < response.length; count++)
    {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' +response[count].id+'</td>';
        html += '<td>€'+response[count].inkoopprijs+'</td>';
        html += '<td>€'+response[count].verkoopprijs+'</td>';
        html += '<td>' +response[count].producten+'</td>';
        html += '<td>' +response[count].create_date+'</td>';
        html += '<td>' +response[count].last_modified+'</td>';
        html += '<td><a href="../prijswijzigen.php?edit='+response[count].id+'" class="edit_btn">Edit</td>';
        html += '<td><a onclick="return confirm()" href="crud.php?del='+response[count].id+'" class="del_btn">Delete</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        serial_no++;
    }
}
```

`

```
        html += '<td>' +response[count].last_modified+'</td>';
```

That line is for my variable last modified that is the same as my create_date variable.

The DOM lastModified property in HTML. That displayed the time of the last time i modified the file.

Comment: What time does the "last modified" for the table describe? And how is that different to the document? (you say `I can only find the last modified time on the document.` so you have a last modified date?). And where does `response` and its content come from?

Comment: the last modified for the table is purely a variable in my sql databse that im displaying, if i edit the variable with my form the date goes to 0000/00/00

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

is that what you need?

Comment: how does this work exactly?

Comment: I assume the `last modified` property describes when the post was last edited or modified correct? So every time a post gets modified, you can set the variable to `new Date().toLocaseDateString()`, which gives a clean formatted date.

Comment: Correct, when the post is last modified, I want that variable to change. I'm going to look up how I can use new Date().toLocaseDateString into my project. If this works, you are very helpful.

Comment: you're welcome. You can mark my answer above as a correct answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but is there a way you can help me with that function?

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: To help me import that function to connect it with the editing the variable, so it knows what time to display.